# Running a script in PowerShell that repeats every 300s that won't print Get-Date

Tags: powershell

super new to scripting and this script was found online and has been edited slightly.
I figured I'd try to make it print the time after each cycle, but can't make it print an updated time; it just repeats the first printed time.

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$today = Get-Date -format t

while ($true)
{
    $myshell.sendkeys("{F15}")
    Write-Host "Last Run $today"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}
```

I've tried "Write-Output" as well but no change.
[Picture of Write-Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRtW2.png)

Comment: The line `$today = Get-Date -format t` needs to go inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Date` is only called once, before your loop so that's why it always displays the same date time.

If you modify your code like this:

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$today = Get-Date -format t

while ($true)
{
    $myshell.sendkeys("{F15}")
    Write-Host "Last Run $(Get-Date -format t)"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}
```

It will call `Get-Date` from within the loop.

Comment: ah... That makes perfect sense when you explain it. 
Thank you so much!